# “Bananagrams” under black light?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, home-experiment

[image: Banagrams glowing in UV]There is a game called “Bananagrams” which includes a bunch of pieces with a letter on each. It seems when I shine a black light flashlight on the letters, the “M” letters glow, but no other pieces do.

*All the pieces appear the same under normal lights (except of course the letters on each piece).* Why would *only* the M’s glow, can someone explain what may be happening here?

Comment: clearly there is an $M^{\dagger}\gamma^{\mu}M$ term some where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blocks with the M came from a different batch than the others. There is no way to know why without more information.

It could have been that a previous batch of M blocks was defective (e.g. incomplete letters due to a defective M die) and had to be replaced, but that is pure speculation and there could be many other explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously either the 'M' pieces are made of some different material which flouresces, or they are painted / coated with some material that does while the other pieces are not.

I would be tempted to mail the makers and say, basically, 'I found this interesting thing' and ask them if they know: they look like they are fairly small and you might therefore get to talk to someone who actually knows about the manufacturing.

Comment: I did send them an email about an hour ago, no response yet, but I will post what they say if and when I get one.